# Conditionally add associative element to array

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements, associative-array, conditional-operator

How can I conditionally add `'b' =>  'xyz'` in the array below, in the array() statement?

`$arr = array('a' => abc)`

The ternary operator doesn't let me do it.

Comment: like `$arr = array('a' => abc, $condition ? ('b' => 'xyz') :, );` or something...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$a = array('a' => 'abc') + ($condition ? array('b' => 'xyz') : array());
```

Comment: @user815340: It is especially more difficult to understand... always strive after readability.

Comment: @FelixKling although correct, readability is not always possible.

Answer (score 16):

In **PHP 8.1** you can do this with array unpacking:

```
$arr = [
    'foo' => 'bar', 
    ...($condition ? ['baz' => 'boo' ] : []),
];
```

See https://php.watch/versions/8.1/spread-operator-string-array-keys

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but you can accomplish this with array_merge:

```
array_merge(['foo' => 'bar'], $condition ? ['baz' => 'boo' ] : []);
```

Answer (score 7):

You need two steps:

```
$arr = array('a' => 'abc');

if(condition) {
    $arr['b'] = 'xyz';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array('a' => 'abc');
if ($condition_required_for_b_to_be_put_in_the_array) {
   $arr['b'] = 'xyz';
}
```

If you *really* want to use the ternary operator:

```
$arr = array('a' => 'abc', $condition ? 'b' : '' => $condition ? 'xyz' : '');
$arr = array_filter($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking; why not

```
if (condition) { 
   $arr['b'] = 'xyz';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary means three terms.  You must have a condition, a true part, and a false part.  It takes the place of if condition then true part else false part.  You can't leave out the third part.  There is a shortcut in 5.3 that allows you to leave out the true part if the condition can be used also as the true part but it still really has three terms.

Answer (score 0):

`array_merge()`, `array_replace()`, the "array union operator", and array unpacking are all potentially suitable tools to add associative elements to an associative array.

Note that if your associative array has numeric keys, there may be a risk of overwriting elements while joining the arrays together.

Here's a demonstration of the aforementioned techniques and how they affect the output based on the order of the original array and the conditionally added element(s) considering the impact of key collisions. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/jhXEW)

Inputs:

```
$arr = ['a' => 'abc'];
$add = ['b' => 'bar', 'a' => 'foo'];
```

---

```
echo json_encode(array_merge($arr, count($add) > 1 ? $add : []));
// {"a":"foo","b":"bar"}
```

---

```
echo json_encode(array_replace($arr, count($add) > 1 ? $add : []));
// {"a":"foo","b":"bar"}
```

---

```
echo "\n---\n";

echo json_encode($arr + (count($add) > 1 ? $add : []));
// {"a":"abc","b":"bar"}
```

---

```
echo json_encode((count($add) > 1 ? $add : []) + $arr);
// {"b":"bar","a":"foo"}
```

---

```
echo json_encode([...$arr, ...count($add) > 1 ? $add : []]);
// {"a":"foo","b":"bar"}
```

---

```
echo json_encode([...count($add) > 1 ? $add : [], ...$arr]);
// {"b":"bar","a":"abc"}
```