# Is it possible to append nothing to an array?

Tags: php

I am wondering if it is possible to append "nothing" to an array, i.e. the array won't be affected. The scenario is that I would like to use the `? :` operators to append values to an array **if** it exists. Otherwise nothing should be appended. I am aware that I can solve this with an ordinary `if` statement without the `else` part. But is there a way to tell PHP that it should append "nothing"? I'm just curious if there's a method for this?

```
<?php
$source_arr = ["Car" => "Volvo", "City" => "Stockholm", "Country" => "Sweden"];
$new_arr    = [];

$new_arr[] = (key_exists("Car",   $source_arr)) ? $source_arr["Car"]   : [];
$new_arr[] = (key_exists("State", $source_arr)) ? $source_arr["State"] : [];  
// An ordinary if statement works of course:
// if (key_exists("State", $source_arr)) { $new_arr[] = $source_arr["State"]; }
// But, is it possible to use ? : and append "nothing" (i.e. not using []) if key doesn't exist?

echo "<pre>";
var_export($new_arr);
echo "</pre>";

// The above outputs (and I understand why):
//   array (
//    0 => 'Volvo',
//    1 => 
//    array (
//    ),
//  )
// 
// But I want the following result (but I don't know if it's possible with ? :)
//   array (
//     0 => 'Volvo',
//   )

?>
```

Comment: `if key_exists(...) { $new_arr[] = ... }`?

Comment: @mousetail *"An ordinary if statement works of course:"* - They know that. Their question is asking about using a ternary `? ... : ...` instead of an `if` statement.

Comment: @mousetail Yes, I am aware of that as I mentioned in the question :)

Comment: @Gowire since you started the line as `$new_arr[] = ...`, it will _always_ append something. But if the code after `?` is `$new_arr[] = ...`, then it will only append if the condition before `?` is `true`. `key_exists('Car', $source_arr) ? $new_arr[] = $source_arr["Car"] : null`

Comment: I'm struggling to see how trying to solve something like this when the simplest and most obvious solution is to us an `if` statement.

Comment: @NigelRen I don't think there's anything wrong with questions asking "can I do this ...", so long as they show an attempt. In this case, it was very close, just had to shuffle the code around a bit. I do also agree that an `if()` statement (or one of the answers below) is a better approach, but that's beside the point, right?

Comment: There is a very good comment about this on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053257/if-without-else-ternary-operator
"The ternary operator is not equivalent to if/else. It's actually an expression that has to have a value."

Comment: @TimLewis How are those counterexamples? `null` is a value.

Comment: What you're trying to do seems poorly designed. It's weird to have an indexed array whose elements are heterogenous and can be optional. If you don't add a value for `Car` to the array, how wil you know what the first element in the new array represents?

Comment: [conditionally adding a element in a array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6477903/2943403) and [A conditional element inside an array(...) construct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4118875/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it when assigning to `$array[]`. You can do it with a function that takes an array argument, by wrapping the value to be added in an array, and using an empty array as the alternate value. `array_merge()` is such a function.

```
$new_array = array_merge($new_array, 
    key_exists("Car", $source_arr) ? [$source_arr["Car"]] : [],
    key_exists("State", $source_arr) ? [$source_arr["State"]] : []
);
```

Comment: This advice is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4118886/2943403

Answer (score 0):

Even better, get everything in one line using [`array_intersect_key`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

```php
$source_arr = ["Car" => "Volvo", "City" => "Stockholm", "Country" => "Sweden"];
$new_arr    = array_intersect_key($source_arr, ['Car'=>'','State'=>'']);

var_export($new_arr);
```

The above outputs the following:

```
array (
  'Car' => 'Volvo',
)
```

If you really do want a non-associative, indexed array, just pass the result of `array_intersect_key` to `array_values`:

```php
$new_arr = array_values(array_intersect_key($source_arr, ['Car'=>'','State'=>'']));
```

```
array (
  0 => 'Volvo',
)
```

[Check both methods here.](https://onlinephp.io?s=nY1BCoMwEEX3Be8whEIseIM2duERhG6shJAOKNqMjFHr7ZumWLrqorP6_D-8dzoPzZDs9iNNbFEbZlBQicKwAJWDuFA_k8hAFK1f31XpyXYN9fdY0-Q8b8uCN3SiPgagwyXSwikIway6dR55ROt1h2v6pcygksEoVS5lJktvPMZcHwIp2c2GNT4GYp9u2NeAtiEQVyfi00e42WbTTzimf6t_uJ8%2C&v=8.1.11%2C7.4.32)

Comment: The intended result is an indexed array, not an associative array. But it seems misguided to me, since indexed arrays should normally be homogeneous.

Comment: @Barmar yes, thanks I missed that detail probably because it made no sense

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you absolutely can "push nothing" conditionally.

Use the splat operator to unpack an array with zero or one element in it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JRRmR))

```
$source_arr = ["Car" => "Volvo", "City" => "Stockholm", "Country" => "Sweden"];
$new_arr    = [];

array_push(
    $new_arr,
    ...key_exists("Car",   $source_arr) ? [$source_arr["Car"]] : [],
    ...key_exists("State", $source_arr) ? [$source_arr["State"]] : []
);

var_export($new_arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could always add the new value (i.e., even if it's empty) and then remove the empties with `array_filter()` when you're done adding:

```
$new_arr = array_filter([
    $source_arr["Car"] ?? null,
    $source_arr["State"] ?? null,
]);
```

Of course, the problem here is that you'll never be able to rely on what's in the array. Is the first element car? Is it city? Country? You'll never know.

Comment: Not to nitpick but this will generate a different output than using an `if (key_exists...` in the event that the key *does exist* but contains a falsey value.  With your code, if `source_arr["State"] == 0` it will not get appended. That's probably what the OP wants anyway but it's good for a beginner to bear in mind.

Comment: @EatenbyaGrue I think you're confusing `??` with `?:`

Comment: @Barmar - no. In this answer if `$source_arr["Car"] == 0` it will get filtered out and removed.  That's what `array_filter()` does without an explicit callback - anything falsey gets removed.

Comment: Right, I was focusing just on the use of the null-coalescing operator. However, the OP's data seems to be strings, so this is probably moot.