# If statement within an array declaration ...is that possible?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, spread

Here is my code

```
$product_option_value_data[] = array(
    'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
    if (isset($product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'])) {
        'smallimage'                  => $product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'],
    }
    'name'                    => $product_option_value_description_query->row['name'],
    'price'                   => $product_option_value['price'],
    'prefix'                  => $product_option_value['prefix']
);
```

can i do something like this....

here is my error

```
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ')' in /Users/mattelhotiby/Sites/posnation/shop_pos/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 419
```

Actually i did this

```
if (isset($product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'])) {
    $smallimage = $product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'];
}else{
    $smallimage = '';
}
$product_option_value_data[] = array(
    'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
    'smallimage'                  => $smallimage,
    'name'                    => $product_option_value_description_query->row['name'],
    'price'                   => $product_option_value['price'],
    'prefix'                  => $product_option_value['prefix']
);
```

But I still want to know if there is a way to do an if within this array declaration.

Comment: you cannot put an if inside an array like that. why not just do it after your initial assignment?

Comment: same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118875/a-conditional-element-inside-an-array-construct

Answer (score 31):

Not an if, but a similar thing is possible:

```
$product_option_value_data[] = array(
    'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
    'smallimage' => (isset($product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'])) ?
        $product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'] : null,
    'name'                    => $product_option_value_description_query->row['name'],
    'price'                   => $product_option_value['price'],
    'prefix'                  => $product_option_value['prefix']
);
```

Syntax:

```
(<statement> ? <case: true> : <case: false>)
(1 == 1 ? 'yes!' : 'PHP is wrong')
```

Comment: PHP docs: [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this one?

```
$array = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
);

if (isset(...)) {
    $array['key3'] = 'value3';
}

$multiarray[] = $array;
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case only possible option is to use following syntax:

```
'smallimage' => (isset($product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage']) 
  ? isset($product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'])
    : NULL)
```

Though this has side effect, if your condition fails you will have "smallimage" key with value of NULL

Comment: I did like this answer, but the 'true' value of the ternary (here, "isset($product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'])" displayed a value of 1, for true.
Change that to "$product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage']" if you want the displayed value to be smallimage.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the array and then add some items:

```
$des = array(...);
if(...)
   $des["..."] = "...";
```

Comment: This worked great - thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

No, You can do it inline or externaly:

```
$product_option_value_data[] = array(
    'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
    'smallimage'                  => @$product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'],
    'name'                    => $product_option_value_description_query->row['name'],
    'price'                   => $product_option_value['price'],
    'prefix'                  => $product_option_value['prefix']
);
```

Or if `smallimage` cannot be empty:

```
$product_option_value_data[] = array(
    'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
    'name'                    => $product_option_value_description_query->row['name'],
    'price'                   => $product_option_value['price'],
    'prefix'                  => $product_option_value['prefix']
);

if (isset($product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'])) {
    $product_option_value_data['smallimage'] = $product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'];
}
```

Comment: what is the  @$product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'], mean

Comment: Lines prefixed by `@` will not raise errors when notices occurs. So, if `smallimage` is not present in  `$product_option_value_description_query->row` array, it will return null and no notice error will be shown

Comment: Note however that if 'Scream' is enabled the suppression will be ignored.

Comment: For multi dimensional array do add the position to append the value i.e.       `$product_option_value_data[sizeof($product_option_value_data-1)]['smallimage'] = $product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'];`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no. But why would you even do that, that is a bad idea. You should only be setting variables in an array, do you logic outside.

```
$data = array(
    'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
    'name'                    => $product_option_value_description_query->row['name'],
    'price'                   => $product_option_value['price'],
    'prefix'                  => $product_option_value['prefix']
);

if (isset($product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'])) {
    $data['small_image'] = $product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'];
}

$product_option_value_data[] = $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

**NO**. Simple as that.

Do:

```
$product_option_value_data[] = array(
    'product_option_value_id' => $product_option_value['product_option_value_id'],
    'name'                    => $product_option_value_description_query->row['name'],
    'price'                   => $product_option_value['price'],
    'prefix'                  => $product_option_value['prefix']
);

if (isset($product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'])) {
     $product_option_value_data[count($product_option_value_data) - 1]['smallimage'] = $product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'],
     // I'm not sure if you meant to have that [] in your declaration above
     // You may need to drop it, in which case the line would be:
     // $product_option_value_data['smallimage'] = $product_option_value_description_query->row['smallimage'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could do that it is much more readable to add the conditional after or before the array.