# Return Different PHP Array Values Based on A User ID-Related Constant

Tags: php, html, arrays, constants, token

I am working with an array of tokens for an HTML template.  Two of them ('{SYS_MENU}' and '{SUB_MENU}') are used to generate control buttons for the web application.  Right now the buttons show up on the login page before the user's credential's are validated, and I need to change the code so that the buttons are hidden until after users login and reach the main menu.  When someone types the http: address into their browser and arrives at the login page the system starts a session for them in the MySQL sessions table with USER_ID = 0.  After they login the USER_ID changes to whatever number was assigned to them at initial registration (Example: USER_ID = 54), and after they logout at the end of the session back to 0.  Tying this constant to the buttons seems like the best solution and I have found it to work in the past under similar circumstances.

Here is the original array:

```
$template_vars = array(

    '{LANG_DIR}' => $lang_text_dir,
    '{TITLE}' => theme_page_title($section),
    '{CHARSET}' => $charset,
    '{META}' => $meta,
    '{GAL_NAME}' => $CONFIG['gallery_name'],
    '{GAL_DESCRIPTION}' => $CONFIG['gallery_description'],
    '{SYS_MENU}' => theme_main_menu('sys_menu'),
    '{SUB_MENU}' => theme_main_menu('sub_menu'),
    '{ADMIN_MENU}' => theme_admin_mode_menu(),
    '{CUSTOM_HEADER}' => $custom_header,
    '{JAVASCRIPT}' => theme_javascript_head(),
    '{MESSAGE_BLOCK}' => theme_display_message_block(),
);
```

The first thing I did was to work with the references directly in the HTML template.  I saw an example on w3schools that made it look like you could just type a PHP script into HTML and have it resolve.  That didn't do anything except echo a bunch of text randomly into the page.  I then found another citation that said you had to activate the PHP with an .HTACCESS entry before it would work directly in HTML.  But that didn't close the deal either.

I know that changing '{SYS_MENU}' and '{SUB_MENU}' values in the array to => "", produces the results that I want (I.E. make the menu buttons disappear).  So my next thought was I'll create an IF statement that returns two versions of the array based on circumstances, something like:

```
if(USER_ID != 0)

{

return  $template_vars = //FIRST VERSION OF ARRAY WITH FULL VALUES//

}

else 

{

return $template_vars = //SECOND VERSION OF ARRAY WITH ONLY => ""//

}
```

But all that did was cause the application load to terminate at a white screen with no error feedback.

My most recent attempt came from something I read here on Stack Overflow.  I know that you cannot put IF statements into an array.  But the article at this link described a workaround:

[If statement within an array declaration ...is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329897/if-statement-within-an-array-declaration-is-that-possible)

So I rewrote the array as follows:

```
template_vars = array(

    '{LANG_DIR}' => $lang_text_dir,
    '{TITLE}' => theme_page_title($section),
    '{CHARSET}' => $charset,
    '{META}' => $meta,
    '{GAL_NAME}' => $CONFIG['gallery_name'],
    '{GAL_DESCRIPTION}' => $CONFIG['gallery_description'],
    '{SYS_MENU}' => ('USER_ID != 0' ? theme_main_menu('sys_menu') : ""),
    '{SUB_MENU}' => ('USER_ID != 0' ? theme_main_menu('sub_menu') : ""),
    '{ADMIN_MENU}' => theme_admin_mode_menu(),
    '{CUSTOM_HEADER}' => $custom_header,
    '{JAVASCRIPT}' => theme_javascript_head(),
    '{MESSAGE_BLOCK}' => theme_display_message_block(),
);
```

But that seems to have no effect at all.  The application doesn't crash but the buttons are static whether you are logged in or logged out.

My question is: What am I missing?  I can see that this is possible.  But I've been trying things for a day and a half and just seem to be dancing around the solution.  Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't return ... just assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are calling return.  With a global include file like this there is not context to return to so the application terminates. What you want to do is just assign the variables.

```
if(USER_ID != 0)
{
   $template_vars = //FIRST VERSION OF ARRAY WITH FULL VALUES//
}
else 
{
   $template_vars = //SECOND VERSION OF ARRAY WITH ONLY => ""//
}
```

Comment: Thanks Orangepill.  That got it working.  My mistake was thinking that you needed return to internally send the result on (like echo except only printing for the benefit of the code).