# How can I use an if statement inside an array?

Tags: arrays, symfony, oop, if-statement, formbuilder

I try to make an if-statement inside an array:

```
  $formBuilder->add('getTimestamp', DateType::class, array(
              'widget' => 'single_text',
               if($target == "new"){
                  'data' => new \DateTime(),
                }
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'line-height: 20px;'), 'label' => $field['fieldName'],
               ));
```

But I get an error message

> (1/1) ParseError
>
> syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If statement within an array declaration ...is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329897/if-statement-within-an-array-declaration-is-that-possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'data' => $target == 'new' ? new \DateTime() : ''
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `if` inside your array. This is not valid php syntax. You could move this outside.

```
$options = [
     'widget' => 'single_text',
     'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'line-height: 20px;'), 'label' => $field['fieldName'],
];
if($target == "new"){
    $options['data'] = new \DateTime();
}

$formBuilder->add('getTimestamp', DateType::class, $options);
```