# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')' in D:\xampp\htdocs\ramesh\wmw\catalog\controller\product\sub_category.php on line 29

Tags: if-statement, opencart, href

I received this error while trying to run the `if statement` for different `href`

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')' in D:\xampp\htdocs\ramesh\wmw\catalog\controller\product\sub_category.php on line 29

**sub_category.php**

```
foreach ($category_info as $result) {
        $data['categories'][] = array(
        'name' => $result['name'],
        'parent_id' => $result['parent_id'],
        'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_category_width'), this->config->get('config_image_category_height')),
        'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
        /*'href' => $this->url->link('product/filter', '&category_id=' . $result['category_id'])
        'href' => $this->url->link('product/sub_category')*/
        if($result['category_id']==24)
        {
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/transmission', 'sub_category_id='.$result['parent_id'].'&category_id=' . $result['category_id'])
    }
    elseif
    {
            /*some code for href*/
        }

      );
}
```

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118875/a-conditional-element-inside-an-array-construct.

Comment: thanks for replay @PhilipTzou sorry am not understand please tell me in my code. It's easy to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i got the answer following code working fine

```
 foreach ($category_info as $result) {
 if($result['category_id']==24)
 {
    $link1 = $this->url->link('product/transmission', 'sub_category_id='.$result['parent_id'].'&category_id=' . $result['category_id']);
 }
else
{
    $link1 = $this->url->link($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
}
$data['categories'][] = array(
    'name' => $result['name'],
    'parent_id' => $result['parent_id'],
    'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_category_height')),
    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
    /*'href' => $this->url->link('product/filter', '&category_id=' . $result['category_id'])
    'href' => $this->url->link('product/sub_category')
    'href' => $this->url->link('product/transmission', 'sub_category_id='.$result['parent_id'].'&category_id=' . $result['category_id'])*/
    'href' => $link1
);
```

}

Comment: I got the result

Answer (score 0):

Your code syntax is wrong. If else conditions are not allowed with in an array.

Please replace your code with the following and error will be resolved -

foreach ($category_info as $result) {
        $href = '';

```
    if ($result['category_id']==24) {
        $href = $this->url->link('product/transmission', 'sub_category_id='.$result['parent_id'].'&category_id=' . $result['category_id']);
    } else {
        /*some code for href*/
    }

    $data['categories'][] = array(
    'name' => $result['name'],
    'parent_id' => $result['parent_id'],
    'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_category_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_category_height')),
    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
    /*'href' => $this->url->link('product/filter', '&category_id=' . $result['category_id'])
    'href' => $this->url->link('product/sub_category')*/        
    'href' => $href    

  );
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Knowband Plugins  But my code working fine